# In $k[x,y]/(xy^2-x)$, $(x)＝(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $k$ be a field and $R＝k[x,y]/(xy^2-x)$. I want to check $(x)＝(xy)$ in $R$.

I understand $(x)＝(xy^2)$ but I cannot proceed from here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show that $(xy)\subseteq(x)$? what about $(x)\subseteq(xy)$? where are you stuck? what have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a very simple fact:

> Let $R$ be a ring. For all $a,b \in R$ you have $(ab) \subseteq (a)$.

Now apply this fact to your setting:

$(xy) \subseteq (x)$ is obvious.

$(xy^2) \subseteq (xy)$ is obvious too, because $xy^2=xy \cdot y$.

But now, as you say
$$(xy^2) \subseteq (xy)\subseteq (x) = (xy^2)$$
Hence all these ideals are equal. In particular $(xy)=(x)$.